# Using a variable as another variable in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zenity

Hi I'm kinda new to bash scripting and not very technical when it comes to writing my own scripts, I have a script that works perfectly in a terminal. I wanted to use zenity to make things nice and simple and straight forward (but also as a little learning project).

The script generates random passwords and with zenity is quite a good little tool.

I have run into a problem though, the script runs well as a GUI but when I wanted to introduce a way for the user to choose the length of the password it fails to produce the password. 
The code to let the user input their desired number (length of password) :

```
number=32
zenity --entry --text="Please enter a number (no limitations!) :" --entry-text="$number"

read newnumber

[ -n "$newnumber" ] && number=$newnumber
```

Which, if run in a terminal displays the number entered in the terminal but not in a zenity box. I cannot use the variable...:

```
number=$newnumber
```

...later in the script as desired like so, I changed a variable from :

```
LENGTH="32"
```

To :

```
LENGTH="$newnumber"
```

The script runs normally (except not producing a password) as a GUI, but in the terminal I get (if the user entered the number 25) :

```
25

/home/server/Desktop/passwd32gen: line 22: [: : integer expression expected
```

So it's the fact I've used `$newnumber`as the value in the `LENGTH=` variable that has broken the generating part of the script. I have tried various different ways to solve this on my own but know too much, I would assume it will be quite a simple missing piece of syntax (or maybe I just hope so).

Now I'm at my wits end trying to figure it out, I've tried

```
declare
```

and

```
eval
```

in a number of ways but they just seemed to break the script.

Thankyou in advance to anyone who can help in anyway!

And please keep in mind I'm looking for a way to use zenity to allow a user to choose the length of the password being generated.

The whole script is :

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # May need to be invoked with  #!/bin/bash2  on older machines.
    #
    #Random 32 character password generator
    #
    zenity --info --title="32 Character Password Generator" --text="Hi, so you want to get yourself a new password? You've the perfect little application here, just click OK to generate your new password."

    number=32
    zenity --entry --text="Please enter a number (no limitations!) :" --entry-text="$number"
    read newnumber
    [ -n "$newnumber" ] && number=$newnumber

    MATRIX="0123456789<?/_+-!@#$%^&*>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    #  Password will consist of standard characters.
    LENGTH="$newnumber"
    #This variable can be changed for password lenth (need to try get zenity to let user choose that number)


    while [ "${n:=1}" -le "$LENGTH" ]
    # := is "default substitution" operator.
    # So, if 'n' has not been initialized, set it to 1.
    do
    PASS="$PASS${MATRIX:$(($RANDOM%${#MATRIX})):1}"
    # Very clever, but tricky.

    # Starting from the innermost nesting...
    # ${#MATRIX} returns length of array MATRIX.

    # $RANDOM%${#MATRIX} returns random number between 1
    # and [length of MATRIX] - 1.

    # ${MATRIX:$(($RANDOM%${#MATRIX})):1}
    # returns expansion of MATRIX at random position, by length 1. 
    # See {var:pos:len} parameter substitution in Chapter 9.
    # and the associated examples.

    # PASS=... simply pastes this result onto previous PASS (concatenation).

    # to let zenity show the password being built one character at a time, uncomment the following line
    # zenity --info --text="$PASS"
    let n+=1
    # Increment 'n' for next pass.
    done

    zenity --info --title="Your 32 character password" --text="Here is your random 32 character password, you can copy and paste it wherever you wish...


    $PASS



    The passwords generated by this application are very strong, here are the numbers;

    Length:                  32 characters
    Character Combinations:  96
    Calculations Per Second: 4 billion
    Possible Combinations:   2 vigintillion

    Based on an average Desktop PC making about 4 Billion calculations per second

    It would take about 21 quattuordecillion years to crack your password.

    As a number that's 21,454,815,022,336,020,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years!"      # you could redirect to a file, to store the password. Use something like $PASS 2> /file/name

    exit 0
```

Comment: For the literal question asked in your title (using indirect variables), see BashFAQ #6: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 -- however, that doesn't appear to be related to your actual problem.

Comment: Also, `set -x` is your friend; `bash -x yourscript` will show you each line as it's executed, so you can figure out exactly where it's going wrong and trim this question down to only contain the bare minimum necessary to show the problem.

Comment: ...see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some guidelines on asking easy-to-answer questions.

Comment: talk about quick, I will check that out now thanks

Comment: Using bash -x seemed to do some good things, I found the script was getting stuck at zenity --entry, so i tried the answer below and it has worked thanks.

Comment: Great! If your problem is now solved, feel free to click the "accepted answer" checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you REALLY want to be able to display the special characters, you can use zenity --text-info as shown below.  It's not as aesthetically pleasing, but it can be done.

Just another 2¢

```
echo "Here is your random $newnumber character password, you can copy and paste it wherever you wish...


$PASS


The passwords generated by this application are very strong, here are the numbers;

Length:                  $newnumber characters
Character Combinations:  96
Calculations Per Second: 4 billion
Possible Combinations:   2 vigintillion

Based on an average Desktop PC making about 4 Billion calculations per second

It would take about 21 quattuordecillion years to crack your password.

As a number that's 21,454,815,022,336,020,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years!" | zenity --text-info --title "Your $newnumber character password" --width 600 --height 500`
```

Addendum,

After playing with it some more, it appears that zenity doesn't like printing variables with special characters.

#### This script should work

I made 2 changes.

1 newnumber=`zenity....  This will read the input from zenity.

2 Removed some special characters from the MATRIX

I marked all changes with #CHANGED

Here's the revised script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# May need to be invoked with  #!/bin/bash2  on older machines.
#
#Random 32 character password generator
#
zenity --info --title="32 Character Password Generator" --text="Hi, so you want to get yourself a new password? You've the perfect little application here, just click OK to generate your new password."

number=32
# CHANGED
newnumber=`zenity --entry --text="Please enter a number (no limitations!) :" --entry-text="$number"`
# read newnumber
[ -n "$newnumber" ] && number=$newnumber
#CHANGED Removed offending special characters
MATRIX="0123456789?_+-!$%^>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
#  Password will consist of standard characters.
LENGTH="$newnumber"
#This variable can be changed for password lenth 
#(need to try get zenity to let user choose that number)


while [ "${n:=1}" -le "$LENGTH" ]
# := is "default substitution" operator.
# So, if 'n' has not been initialized, set it to 1.
do
PASS="$PASS${MATRIX:$(($RANDOM%${#MATRIX})):1}"
# Very clever, but tricky.

# Starting from the innermost nesting...
# ${#MATRIX} returns length of array MATRIX.

# $RANDOM%${#MATRIX} returns random number between 1
# and [length of MATRIX] - 1.

# ${MATRIX:$(($RANDOM%${#MATRIX})):1}
# returns expansion of MATRIX at random position, by length 1. 
# See {var:pos:len} parameter substitution in Chapter 9.
# and the associated examples.

# PASS=... simply pastes this result onto previous PASS (concatenation).

# to let zenity show the password being built one character at a time, uncomment the following line
# zenity --info --text="$PASS"
let n+=1
# Increment 'n' for next pass.
done
# CHANGED $PASS to '$PASS' below
zenity --info --title="Your 32 character password" --text="Here is your random 32 character password, you can copy and paste it wherever you wish...


$PASS



The passwords generated by this application are very strong, here are the numbers;

Length:                  32 characters
Character Combinations:  96
Calculations Per Second: 4 billion
Possible Combinations:   2 vigintillion

Based on an average Desktop PC making about 4 Billion calculations per second

It would take about 21 quattuordecillion years to crack your password.

As a number that's 21,454,815,022,336,020,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years!"      # you could redirect to a file, to store the password. Use something like $PASS 2> /file/name

exit 0
```

Comment: thanks that works just as well as @Charles answer, except i feel using single quotes for the $PASS variable doesnt change anything but causes a problem as the single quotes are displayed in the dialog box so the password is always going to be them two characters longer when copied.

Comment: Sorry, I did remove the single quotes from the variable, but I forgot to remove the comment when updating the script.  It was the special characters causing the problems.

Comment: What's this about removing special characters? bash can represent literally any ASCII character other than a NUL in a string, even if it requires a bit of care.

Comment: @MPH426 you have answered my question the removal of the characters </@#&* has worked, obviously it was getting stuck trying to produce and understand those characters. An explanation of why it doesn't like those characters would good if any body knows?

Comment: It's not bash that has the problem with the special characters.  Zenity appears to be the culprit.  If you remove all references to zenity and code it as a straight bash script, you wouldn't have the same problem.  I've run into this a few times with PHP and other languages.  There are also some instances where you can't use certain characters.  My ISP's login for example, won't allow the ! symbol for some reason.

Comment: @Jack Herer,  BTW, thanks for the _clever_ method of generating the password.  I wrote a random password generator back in 2007.  It's much more cumbersome that that "one liner" you've got.  I'll have to update my code ;)

Comment: @MPH426 no worries i have to give credit though where credit is due, I found something similar a while back to create 8 character passwords and modified it to return the expansion of MATRIX at a random position by a length of 1 and of course I like zenity too :)...and I agree about zenity being ignorant to certain characters, I will most likely dig around and find out at some point, and as you say some logins are strange about certain characters so it would be good to revise the MATRIX according to a standard I guess

Answer (score 2):

A `read` command following your zenity command won't read *from* zenity -- it still reads from stdin as always.

Instead, you probably want:

```
newnumber=$(zenity --entry \
  --text="Please enter a number (no limitations!) :" \
  --entry-text="$number")
```

...no following `read` command needed.

That said, if you *did* want to use `read` for some reason, you could still do that:

```
read -r newnumber < <(zenity --entry \
  --text="Please enter a number (no limitations!) :" \
  --entry-text="$number")
```

Comment: both of these worked a couple of times but as i tried differentwithumbers the script has now become unstable and i have resulted in my original problem, i have tried to implement them in various ways but nothing generates the password.

Comment: (zenity:3861): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
+ number=32
+ read -r newnumber
++ zenity --entry '--text=Please enter a number (no limitations!) :' --entry-text=32
No protocol specified

(zenity:3863): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
+ MATRIX='0123456789<?/_+-!@#$%^&*>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
+ LENGTH=
+ '[' 1 -le '' ']'
passwd32gen: line 23: [: : integer expression expected

Comment: @JackHerer, that's a problem with your X configuration, not a bash issue.

Comment: If I choose to generate 10 characters it works.....15 it works....20 it wont work.....15 it wont work....10 it works....15 it works....20 it wont work....10 it works!!! any chance you know why it could do that?

Comment: In what way would it be my X configuration?

Comment: `Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0` means that zenity can't connect to your X server. That's not going to have anything to do with how many characters you're generating, and it's the issue you should start by solving.

Comment: That is only when i run it with bash -x if i run it by clicking the file or run the command in the terminal it runs, it will continually produce a password in the dialog in fact i just ran it and chose 10 characters over 30 times and its flawless, as soon as i chose a number over 20 it wont produce a password.

Comment: @JackHerer Sounds almost like your stderr is getting buffered somewhere without a reader, and eventually filling the buffer and blocking. Can't really do anything to debug that without knowing more about your runtime environment, though -- but if you're, say, piping stderr from `bash -x` to `less`, that would explain it. By the way, `for ((n=0; n<length; n++))` is probably easier to read than your `while` loop. (Non-environment, non-builtin variables should be given lower-case names to avoid conflicting with environment variables and shell builtins).

Comment: Thanks again, great advice, I have modified with    for ((n=0; n<length; n++)) the problem has been answered below  i.e. certain not special characters.

Comment: I have been using the script over and over and have since discovered that by using `for ((n=0; n<length; n++))` it doesnt generate the number asked for.. instead choosing to generate to the closest half. So if i choose `7` it will produce a `4` character password, and `8` would produce `4` and `9` would produce `5` and `10` would produce `5`.. and so on, so I changed it back to `while [ "${n:=1}" -le "$length" ]` and it works fine.

Comment: @JackHerer, `-le` is `<=`, not `<`. Trivial change. Also, since the loop has its own `n++`, you need to remove `let n=n+1` when using the C-style for approach.

Comment: somehow this is producing a +1.. if I choose`50` its gives a length of `51`

Comment: Then `<` was correct, but you hadn't taken out the `let` earlier.

Comment: sorry thats my mistake I should have spotted that, I'm getting too tired, thankyou for all your help @Charles