# zenity --info dialog is unstable

Tags: bash, shell, zenity

I have a script that randomly generates passwords, I have modified it to display in a GUI using `zenity`. When I use the original script, I can produce random passwords of any length the user chooses (I tested with 50,000). Here's the code :

```
    #!/bin/bash
    number=10
    echo "hello"
    echo "Please enter your number: $number"
    read newnumber
    # read newnumber
    [ -n "$newnumber" ] && number=$newnumber

    MATRIX="0123456789<?/_+-!@#$%^&*>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    #  Password will consist of standard characters.
    LENGTH=$newnumber
    #This variable can be changed for password lenth (need to try get zenity to let user choose that number)


    while [ "${n:=1}" -le "$LENGTH" ]
    # := is "default substitution" operator.
    # So, if 'n' has not been initialized, set it to 1.
   do
   PASS="$PASS${MATRIX:$(($RANDOM%${#MATRIX})):1}"
    # Very clever, but tricky.

    # Starting from the innermost nesting...
    # ${#MATRIX} returns length of array MATRIX.

    # $RANDOM%${#MATRIX} returns random number between 1
    # and [length of MATRIX] - 1.

    # ${MATRIX:$(($RANDOM%${#MATRIX})):1}
    # returns expansion of MATRIX at random position, by length 1. 
    # See {var:pos:len} parameter substitution in Chapter 9.
    # and the associated examples.

    # PASS=... simply pastes this result onto previous PASS (concatenation).

    # to let zenity show the password being built one character at a time, uncomment the following line
            # zenity --info --text="$PASS"
    let n+=1
    # Increment 'n' for next pass.
    done

    echo "$PASS"
```

(I have followed on from [another question][1]

[1]: [Using a variable as another variable in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508386/using-a-variable-as-another-variable-in-a-bash-script) )

My problem is now that when try produce higher length passwords they wont display in the `zenity --info` dialog box, anything over 30 is hit or miss. I have got it to display a 60 character by repeatedly running the script and choosing 60 each time but its not good enough to be so hit or miss, 9 times out of 10 it will produce less than 20 characters and struggles more the higher the length it has to generate. But only in `zenity`

Any help is of course greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer and it's annoyingly simple... the characters `</@#&*` would cause the generator to crash when used with zenity, but does anyone know why?

Comment: Look at `man bash` for reserved words. You will need to escape several of the characters with `\\` to prevent them from being interpreted by the shell. (or **single-quote** your string assignment to MATRIX)